# How do I connect to my work computer from my home computer and borrow its IP? VPN?

Tags: vpn, remote-access

My work computer has access to IP-restricted resources within my company. I need (well, want) access to those from home. How do I go about connecting to my work machine and using it as a pass-through, just so I can get to internal system resources? Is this what VPN is for? Is there some stupid simple way to setup a VPN server to do what I want?

Comment: Just because this is one of the most duplicated questions I see here I'm not going to put this as an answer. However: www.Teamviewer.com will do what you want.

Comment: Talk to your IT support group.  Going outside of the established boundaries and policies of your workplace to gain access to your work network from home using any unapproved method is ALWAYS a bad idea, regardless of your intent.  Talk to them.  If they don't allow it, there's a good reason.  Forget it and move on.  If there is an approved method and they see a reason for you to be able to use it, they'll help you get it set up.

Answer (score 2):

A workaround may be to install [**LogMeIn Free**](https://secure.logmein.com/products/free/) on your work computer and effectively take control of it from your home computer to do what you need to do.  Your work computer would need to remain switched on for this to work.

As quite rightly put by BBlake in the comment above, I would seek advice from your IT department before you do this or you could end up in a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a VPN is exactly what you need. OpenVPN is free.

Comment: But the IT department would have to set it up. A sane network administrator would not allow just anyone to enable it?